# Uninstall Angular and NodeJs completely and reinstall

Tags: angular, version

I am trying to uninstall angular and nodeJs completely and reinstall them.
I used these code to uninstall angular

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

For node uninstallation I could not find a code.
Any help??
I am doing this because I am getting this error

```
C:\Users\chalani>ng update @angular/cdk --next
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest pre-release version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Unknown error: Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\chalani\AppData\Local\Temp\angular-cli-packages-BuVCKr\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\uuid'
```

when updating to new version and also for any *ng* command even for *ng version*

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen with Node v13; either downgrade to LTS v12.16.3 or upgrade to latest v14.2.0.